# GCP composer 2 GKE nodes not registering

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-composer, gke-networking

I am trying to create a Composer 2 environment in GCP, with most things set to default configuration. I am using a shared vpc for network and the subnet is pretty standard with /24 cidr range. I am using two pupi secondary ranges for cluster and service ip ranges.

The autopilot GKE cluster creation gets stuck at 83% health check and after about 1 hour it throws this error and deletes itself.

> message: "All cluster resources were brought up, but: 3 nodes out of
> 3 are unhealthy."

The strange thing is that I can't see the nodes tab in the cluster page in console
and there are no vms listed in the project at all.
I don't know if this is standard behaviour for auto-pilot clusters because for normal clusters there is always a nodes tab in cluster page and the vms will be listed as soon as the cluster starts creating.

[image]

[image]

Comment: With Autopilot, you won't be able to see or access the node VMs as they are fully managed by Google.  I'm sure you did this, but I assume you did follow https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/configure-shared-vpc ?

Comment: If your problem is resolved please post the answer so that it would be helpful for the other community members.